# scrolling background in game android studio.Background moves towards right with screen blinking how to solve it

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I want to implement a **scrolling background** in my game in android studio.

My idea was to have two Bitmaps, who are drawn next to each other and to reset the position of a bitmap if it is not the screen anymore

1. The background moves **right**
2. the screen is **blinking**

How can I solve my problems?

my `SurfaceView` class

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

  private Thread thread; // draw + update thread

  int screenx, screeny; // screen size
  Background background1 , background2;

  float screenratiox, screenratioy;

  private boolean isplaying;

  Paint paint;

  public GameView(Context context, int screenx, int screeny) {
    super(context);

    this.screenx = screenx;
    this.screeny = screeny;

    this.screenratiox = 1920f / screenx;
    this.screenratioy = 1080f / screeny;

    background1 = new Background(screenx, screeny, getResources());
    background2 = new Background(screenx, screeny, getResources());

    background2.x = screenx;

    paint = new Paint();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (isplaying) {
      update();
      sleep();
      draw();
    }
  }

  public void sleep() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(17);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void resume() {
    isplaying = true ;
    thread = new Thread(this) ;
    thread.start();
  }

  public void pause() {
    try {
      isplaying = false ;
      thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void update() { //should move the background and reset it, if beyond the screen
    background1.x += 10 * screenratiox; // move
    background2.x += 10 * screenratioy; // move

    if (background1.x + background1.background.getWidth() < 0) {
      background1.x = screenx; //reset x
    } 

    if (background2.x + background2.background.getWidth() < 0) {
      background2.x = screenx; //reset x
    } 
  }

  private void draw () {
    if (getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {

      Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();

      canvas.drawBitmap(background1.background, background1.x, background1.y, paint);
      canvas.drawBitmap(background2.background, background2.x, background2.y, paint);

      getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
  }
}
```

my Background class

```
public class Background {
  int x = 0, y = 0; // position
  Bitmap background; // image

  Background(int screenx , int screeny , Resources res) {
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, screenx, screeny, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the tutorial you watched is a veery bad one.

Comment: please post your full code (sleep, resume + pause methods)

Comment: i have edited my above code with sleep, resume ,and pause method...plz check ...when i use  -= 10  background moves towards left accurately but i want to move it towards right side......background1.x -= 10 * screenratiox; // move 
background2.x -= 10 * screenratioy; // move

Answer (score 0):

> background1.x += 10 * screenratiox; // move
>
> background2.x += 10 * screenratioy; // move

literally means: move the `x` to the right.

So

```
background1.x -= 10 * screenratiox; // move 
background2.x -= 10 * screenratioy; // move
```

Answer (score 0):

background1.x -= (int)(10 * screenratiox);

background2.x -= (int)(10 * screenratiox);

Comment: Please consider to improve your answer with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71693784/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).